# WTForms/Jinja: Getting error when using just the field label

Tags: jinja2, wtforms

I'm getting this error when `label` is not paired with an `input` after it. But since it's Jinja generating the code, how can I fix this?

Error:

```
Incorrect use of <label for=FORM_ELEMENT>
The label's for attribute doesn't match any element id. This might prevent the browser from correctly autofilling the form and accessibility tools from working correctly.
To fix this issue, make sure the label's for attribute references the correct id of a form field.
```

This error shows up in the web developer's tool and does not otherwise, seem to effect anything else. I only see this error with `form_name` and `sort_order` and not with any other fields with a label/field data pairing

Here's my code:

Generated HTML:

```html
<form action="/download" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
    <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="...">

    <form-title> <label for="form_name">Download Form</label> </form-title>

    <form-item class="radio-group">
      <label class="radio-label" for="sort_order">Sort Order</label>

        <input class="radio-btn" id="sort_order-0" name="sort_order" required type="radio" value="ascend">
        <label class="radio-value" for="sort_order-0">Ascending</label>
      
        <input checked class="radio-btn" id="sort_order-1" name="sort_order" required type="radio" value="descend">
        <label class="radio-value" for="sort_order-1">Descending</label>
       
    </form-item>
```

`form.jinja`

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('download_func') }}" name="form" method="post">
<form-title> {{ form.form_name.label(class="form-title") }} </form-title>
<form-item class="radio-group">
{{ form.sort_order.label(class="radio-label") }}
{% for btn in form.sort_order %}
{{ btn(class="radio-btn") }}
{{ btn.label(class="radio-value") }}
{% endfor %} 
</form-item>
    ...
</form>
```

`models.py`

```py
class DownloadForm(FlaskForm): 
    form_name = StringField(u'Download Form')

    sort_order_values = [('ascend', 'Ascending'), 
                         ('descend', 'Descending')]

    sort_order = RadioField(u'Sort Order', choices=sort_order_values, 
                            default='descend', validators=[DataRequired()])
    # other fields
```

Comment: This might possibly be due to a bug: https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/issues/775